# Postgres database restore error :WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 38 Process returned exit code 1

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am using Postgres 9.5.1 and tried to restore Postgres database.Following error appeared:

```
   pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 527; 1255 1117686 FUNCTION pldbg_abort_target(integer) postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plugin_debugger": No such file or directory
        Command was: CREATE FUNCTION pldbg_abort_target(session integer) RETURNS SETOF boolean
        LANGUAGE c STRICT
        AS '$libdir/plugin_debug...
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.pldbg_abort_target(integer) does not exist
        Command was: ALTER FUNCTION public.pldbg_abort_target(session integer) OWNER TO postgres;


    pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.pldbg_attach_to_port(integer)"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 528; 1255 1117687 FUNCTION pldbg_attach_to_port(integer) postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plugin_debugger": No such file or directory
        Command was: CREATE FUNCTION pldbg_attach_to_port(portnumber integer) RETURNS integer
        LANGUAGE c STRICT
        AS '$libdir/plugin_debugg...
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.pldbg_attach_to_port(integer) does not exist
        Command was: ALTER FUNCTION public.pldbg_attach_to_port(portnumber integer) OWNER TO postgres;


    pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.pldbg_continue(integer)"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 529; 1255 1117688 FUNCTION pldbg_continue(integer) postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plugin_debugger": No such file or directory
        Command was: CREATE FUNCTION pldbg_continue(session integer) RETURNS breakpoint
        LANGUAGE c STRICT
        AS '$libdir/plugin_debugger', '...
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.pldbg_continue(integer) does not exist
        Command was: ALTER FUNCTION public.pldbg_continue(session integer) OWNER TO postgres;

     pg_restore: creating FUNCTION "public.pldbg_create_listener()"
        pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 530; 1255 1117689 FUNCTION pldbg_create_listener() postgres
        pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plugin_debugger": No such file or directory
            Command was: CREATE FUNCTION pldbg_create_listener() RETURNS integer
            LANGUAGE c STRICT
            AS '$libdir/plugin_debugger', 'pldbg_creat...
        pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  function public.pldbg_create_listener() does not exist
            Command was: ALTER FUNCTION public.pldbg_create_listener() OWNER TO postgres;
.................
WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 38

Process returned exit code 1.
```

> The error was so long that i have added only few errors.I checked the database and almost all the data appeared in the database.I need help for this error.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to install the EDB PL/pgSQL debugger in the software directory of the destination database to get rid of these error messages.

Also, this seems to be an old version of the debugger, since it is not installed as an extension.

You can safely ignore all errors that belong to this module, since it is just for debugging.

If you need the debugger, get the current version and install it as an extension.

Comment: Ok I will try as you have said.I check  restored database and found out that almost all data appeared.Will this error creates any problem in the database access?

Comment: No, unless you application calls the debugger for PL/pgSQL functions in the database, which would surprise me. Most likely it is just a leftover when someone tried to debug PL/pgSQL functions during the development phase.